# Microservice with REST, MQTT and gRPC using FastAPI?

Tags: rest, mqtt, grpc, fastapi

I'd like to implement the [API Gateway pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html) with FastAPI for an IoT use case. Means a FastAPI service shall expose a REST and MQTT interface to the outside world of the application and shall support gRPC-based communication to "business logic level" microservices. Is this possible with FastAPI and how do I have to make this work (w.r.t. inter-operability of [FastAPI](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi) and e.g. [fastapi-mqtt](https://github.com/sabuhish/fastapi-mqtt), [gRPC Python implementation](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/))?

Comment: I'm not sure about gRPC, since I wasn't aware that there is an extension for MQTT in fastapi, but the basic idea is that you should use an API Gateway that can forward both HTTP and MQTT requests. I would use 2 gateways: one for normal HTTP traffic and one for MQTT traffic. For the latter you can use https://github.com/1technophile/OpenMQTTGateway